# haskell - state monad function get?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

one question according to the get function of the State Monad:

If I run

> runState get 1

I got the result

> (1,1)

and this is ok for me because the get function set the result value to the state and in this case the state is 1. Thus, (1,1) is the result. Ok.

But if I run

> runState (do{(a,b) <- get; return a}) (False, 0)

I got the result

> (False,(False,0))

And this I don't understand.

The get function set the result value to the state and left the state unchanged. So what I would expect is something like this

> ((False,0),(False,0))

The same with this

> runState (do{(a,b) <- get; return b}) (False, 0)

the result is

> (0,(False,0))

I don't understand this again as above descripted.

So, it would be very nice if you could explain me this for me strange results. ;)

Thanks in advance

best regards,

jimmy

Comment: I recommend reading this: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad

Answer (score 9):

It's because you do something after the `get`, namely you `return` one of the components. Ignoring the newtype-wrapping,

```
return x = \s -> (x,s)
```

so

```
do { (a,b) <- get; return a }   ===   get >>= \(a,b) -> return a
```

expands to

```
(\s -> (s,s)) >>= \(a,b) -> (\t -> (a,t))
```

and with the definition of `(>>=)` that becomes

```
\s1 -> let (r,s2) = (\s -> (s,s)) s1
       in (\(a,b) -> (\t -> (a,t))) r s2
```

And when you run that with an initial state of `(False,0)`, it unfolds

```
let (r,s2) = (\s -> (s,s)) (False,0)
~> let (r,s2) = ((False,0),(False,0))
in (\(a,b) -> (\t -> (a,t))) r s2
~> in (\(a,b) -> (\t -> (a,t))) (False,0) (False,0)
~> in (\t -> (False,t)) (False,0)    -- match (a,b) with (False,0)
~> in (False, (False,0))
```

The other case with `return b` is similar.

Comment: One little more question: Could you tell me the definition of the ">>" function in the state monad? That would be very nice. Possibly in "let .. in .." notation like you did it with the ">>=" function above. Again, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @jimmyt `m >> n` is the same thing as `m >>= \_ -> n` that is, it is just monadic bind but discarding the value.  You can think of `m >> n` as meaning "perform m then perform n"

Answer (score 5):

Daniel’s answer is of course correct and complete, so let me try to answer it from a different angle and discuss possible misunderstandings.

You expected `((False,0),(False,0))` to be returned for

```
runState (do{(a,b) <- get; return a}) (False, 0)
```

Now to actually get this expected result, you’d have to write, for example,

```
runState (do{(a,b) <- get; return (a,b)}) (False, 0)
```

(which is morally equivalent to `runState get (False, 0)`.

Maybe you were confusing `get` and `runState`; the latter returns a tuple where one component is the result of the computation and the other the final state. And indeed you’d take that tuple apart to obtain only the (final) state. `get` however has one return value, which is just the (current) state and nothing more – no untupling required. If you do take the tuple apart and return only `a` (or `b`), then this shows up accordingly as the result of the complete stateful computation, just as you have observed.

Comment: Thank you. You both are right. My mistake was a misunderstanding of the bind function >>= in the state monad. What about this: "runState (do{(a, b) <- get; return a}) (x, y)" is equivalent to "let (_, s1) = runState get (x, y) in (z, s2) = runState return x s1"? For instance (x, y) = (False, 0) , then it goes like this: let (_, (False, 0)) = runState get (False, 0) in (False, (False, 0)) = runState return False (False, 0). Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a third answer:

It's true that `get = \s -> (s,s)`, but (in the case of State) the arrow inside the do-notation puts out only the **value**. It's all because of the definition of `bind` for **this** monad.

So, you don't get the whole pair `(s,s)`. All you get is the first `s`.

You provided initial state = `(False,0)`; the `<-` arrow gives you the copied value `(False,0)` and you bind it to `(a,b)`.

You then build a state monad around the value `a = False`. This monad will return `(a,s)` and that's `(False,(False,0))`.

The initial state hasn't changed during the run, because neither `get` nor `return` have modified it.